# Fragment shared element transitions z order broken with AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, shared-element-transition

I have the following layout files:

`fragment_a.xml`

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:transitionName="@string/transition_image" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/scrim"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:transitionName="@string/transition_scrim" />
    
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/contentList"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:transitionName="@string/transition_list" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`fragment_b.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_image" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/scrim"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition_scrim"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/contentList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_list"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am doing shared element transitions between two fragments.

The transition works fine if the toolbar is not starting to collapsed and the `contentList` animates on top of the `scrim` and `image`. If the app bar vertical offset is just a bit different from the expanded value the `scrim` and the `image` will animate on top of the `contentList`. So the z order changes while animating. What is the problem here? Does the app bar change the z value of its children when it's collapsing?